# Codename One - How to apply custom background to command menu tabs

Tags: background, tabs, command, codenameone

I am new to using Codename One and I can't figure out how to apply a custom background (preferrably a tiled .png but even a custom colour will do) to the 'commands' menu tabs.

I can set the title and the icon of each tab in the GUI Builder by going to 'Properties' > 'Commands' > 'Edit', but there is no option to apply a background and they appear with a white background in the simulator.

Not sure if this makes a difference but just in case, in my 'Theme' > 'Constants' I have the following settings:

```
'commandBehavior' = 'bar'
'dialogButtonCommandsBool' = 'true'
'includeNativeBool' = 'false'
```

Appreciate any help on this, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add 'TouchCommand' entry in the Theme and to custom it's appearance.